# Data labels on the bars

Tags: d3.js

I have been trying to get the data labels to appear on the bars of the d3 chart I have built.  No joy.  I have tried svg.selectAll("text")... but no error and no labels.

I have created a codePen [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGVLvz)

```
function arbByMonthDashboard2(targetDiv, monthToReport) {
    var color_hash = {  1 : ["January", "green"],
                2 : ["February", "orange"],
                3 : ["March", "aquamarine"],
                4 : ["April", "blue"],
                5 : ["May", "yellow"],
                6 : ["June", "silver"],
                7 : ["July", "antiquewhite"],
                8 : ["August", "cyan"],
                9 : ["September", "blueviolet"],
                10 : ["October", "black"],
                11 : ["November", "cadetblue"],
                12 : ["December", "red"]
              } 
    var chartData = { "data": [
        { MonthNum: 4, Month: '4-2014', ARBs: 4 },
        { MonthNum: 5, Month: '5-2014', ARBs: 4 },
        { MonthNum: 6, Month: '6-2014', ARBs: 4 },
        { MonthNum: 7, Month: '7-2014', ARBs: 5 },
        { MonthNum: 8, Month: '8-2014', ARBs: 4 },
        { MonthNum: 9, Month: '9-2014', ARBs: 8 },
        { MonthNum: 10, Month: '10-2014', ARBs: 12 },
        { MonthNum: 11, Month: '11-2014', ARBs: 6 },
        { MonthNum: 12, Month: '12-2014', ARBs: 16 },
        { MonthNum: 1, Month: '1-2015', ARBs: 6 },
        { MonthNum: 2, Month: '2-2015', ARBs: 10 },
        { MonthNum: 3, Month: '3-2015', ARBs: 10 },
        { MonthNum: 4, Month: '4-2015', ARBs: 13 },
        { MonthNum: 5, Month: '5-2015', ARBs: 13 }
    ]};
    var width = 400;
    var height = 900;
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%Y").parse;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m-%Y"));

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10);

    var svg = d3.select("#divChart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 

    chartData.data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Month = parseDate(d.Month);
        d.ARBs = +d.ARBs;
        }
    );

    x.domain(chartData.data.map(function(d) { return d.Month; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(chartData.data, function(d) { return d.ARBs;})]);

    svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("dx", "-.8em")
          .attr("dy", "-.55em")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Total ARBs");

      svg.selectAll("bar")
          .data(chartData.data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .style("fill", function(d) { 
                            var color = color_hash[d.MonthNum][1];
                            return color;
                            })
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Month); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.ARBs); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.ARBs); });
};
```

Comment: Where are you trying to append the labels? Note that this is covered in [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you ask, sorry.

You can add text on bar by creating a new selection on your data :

```
svg.selectAll("text.legend")
          .data(chartData.data)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Month) + x.rangeBand() / 2 ; })
                .text(function(d){return d.ARBs})
                .attr('y', height - 10);
```

You have a codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjKwjL

Hope it helps,

Regards